# RDOAttachment.Hidden of attached file is true, when signature contains linked image

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I'm using the following code to save the Outlook attachments to the local file system:

```
  foreach (RDOAttachment attachment in rdoMail.Attachments)
            {
                {
                    if (!attachment.Hidden)
                    {
                        var savePath = tempPath + attachment.FileName;
                        try
                        {
                            log.Trace("Attachment {0} saved : {1}", logIndex, attachment.FileName);
                            attachment.SaveAsFile(savePath);
                            resultList.Add(savePath);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            log.ErrorException("Save Attachment As Exception", exception);
                            log.Trace("Tryed save to path: ", savePath);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When the signature, which contains a linked image, is added to the mail manually before the files are attached to the mail, some of the attached files are marked as hidden. In this case its not possible to identify them as normal attachment or hidden attachment.

When the signature is added automatically to the mail, the problem does not occur. When the signature is added to mail after the files are attached, it also working.

Comment: Can you save the problematic message as an MSG file ,zip it (important!) and send it to redemption (at) dimastr dot com?

Comment: mission accomplished. thanks in advance!